# While writing in Excel cell, all the columns are returning as string

Tags: java

I am using java code.

I need the specific columns in numeric format for calculation. Please check the attached.

```
cell = row.createCell(colno);
cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
cell.setCellValue(Helper.correctNull(nf.format(principalOutstanding)));
cell.setCellStyle(styleCurrencyFormat);
cell.setCellStyle(alignFormat);
cell.setCellStyle(borderStyle);
colno++;
```

Comment: What `Helper.correctNull(nf.format(principalOutstanding))` returns? Number or String? Update your question and add this function's code please. Also are you using XSSF or HSSF? If you are using maven please also post your `pom.xml`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.